# Converting from Sandcastle to DITA usable format

Tags: sandcastle, dita

Novice in DITA or XSL. I am faced with a challange of building documentation for API documentation. Currently I am able to product the HTML and CHM help using Sandcastle on a C# Assembly and an XML. I have a requirement to to produce it in DITA. Any leads?

Thanks

Comment: For any DITA guru's reading, this is the sandcastle he's speaking of: https://sandcastle.codeplex.com/ It can parse code and generate API docs. I've seen a couple of homegrown solutions (http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/dita-users/message/4019) but nothing off the shelf for C#.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, there is a way to migrate HTML to DITA with DITA Open Toolkit. Would this be enough? http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/1.5.2/readme/DITA-h2d.html